# Efetuar várias operações em um único código SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela em MySQL da seguinte forma e estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de executar uma consulta em SQL que fizesse as seguintes operações:

1. Totalizar o número de registros (**total1**);
2. Contar quantos registros possuem id_nps_answer entre 0 e 6 (**total2**);
3. Contar quantos registros possuem id_nps_answer entre 9 e 10 (**total3**);
4. Efetuar o cálculo **((total3 - total2) / total1)**;

O resultado seria disponibilizado ao PHP.

Isso é possível? Não estou conseguindo fazer o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para trazer todos na mesma linha, você teria que aninhar os subselects, assim:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (total3 - total2) / total1 as calculado
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total1 FROM nome_tabela) total1
    JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as total2 from nome_tabela WHERE id_nps_answer between 0 and 6) total2
    JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as total3 from nome_tabela where id_nps_answer between 9 and 10) total3
```

Comment: deu certo. Muito obrigado...

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite! Por favor, avise se o código que eu criei funcionou dpois que vc testar. obrigado.

```
 -- 1 Totalizar o número de registros (total1);
 SELECT COUNT(id_nps_score) 
 FROM nome_da_tabela; 

 -- 2 Contar quantos registros possuem id_nps_answer entre 0 e 6 (total2);
 SELECT COUNT(id_nps_answer)
 FROM nome_da_tabela
 WHERE id_nps_answer BETWEEN 0 and 6;

 -- 3 Contar quantos registros possuem id_nps_answer entre 9 e 10 (total3);
 SELECT COUNT(id_nps_answer)
 FROM nome_da_tabela
 WHERE id_nps_answer BETWEEN 9 and 10;

 -- 4 Efetuar o cálculo ((total3 - total2) / total1);
 SELECT ((resultado3 - resultado2) / resultado1) AS '(total3-total2)/total1='
 FROM nome_da_tabela;
```

Comment: Funcionou sim, porém eu preciso que o scripts sejam todos aninhados aninhados em um único código, essa é a minha dúvida.